# Pazifisch vs. pazifistisch, metabolisch vs. metabolistisch - wie funktionieren diese Suffixe?

Tags: loanword, suffix, latin

Was ist der Hintergrund der Suffixe "-isch" und "-istisch"? An welchen Wörtern werden sie verwendet, was ist ihr unterschied?

Ich vermute, dass letzteres zusammengesetzt ist aus "-ist" und "-isch". Offensichtlich sind beide Suffixe in der deutschen Sprache präsent, und wurden in verschiedenen Epochen zur Konstruktion neuer Adjektive verwendet, obgleich sie teilweise erkaltet sind.

Vergleiche z.B.

> pazifisch / pazifistisch
>
> metabolisch / metabolistisch
>
> egoisch / egoistisch

Es fällt auf, dass jeweils eine der beiden Varianten in Gebrauch ist, während die andere nur in sehr speziellen Kontexten vorkommt, oder, wie im Falle von "pazifisch", nur noch als eigenständiges Adjektiv.

Answer (score 6):

Ich fürchte, dass Du da eine falsche Spur verfolgst – es handelt sich in beiden Fällen Deines ersten Beispiels um dasselbe Suffix, nämlich "-isch": Das Suffix "-ist" ist bereits vorher dran und hat mit dieser Suffigierung gar nichts zu tun.

> Pazifik – pazifisch
>   Pazifist/Pazifismus – pazifistisch

Bei den anderen beiden Beispielen gibt es meines Wissens standardsprachlich jeweils nur einen der beiden von Dir genannten Fälle: metabolisch und egoistisch.

*Möglicherweise* gibt es allerdings daneben auch noch tatsächlich die Geschichte mit den "speziellen Kontexten": Im fachsprachlichen Bereich gibt es mitunter etwas abseitige Wortschöpfungen – die genannten Beispiele "metabolistisch" und "egoisch" klingen stark danach. Besonders "egoisch" klingt nach psychologisch/soziologischem Kontext – bei einer Google-Suche erweist es sich dann auch als Kunstwort, das einen Bezug zum "Ego", allerdings ohne den negativen Beigeschmack zu "Egoismus", ausdrücken soll ([z. B. hier](http://www.sonnwandeln.eu/glossar.html)). Solche Wörter sind in der Nische, in der sie entstanden sind, bestimmt sinnvoll – vom Gebrauch in "normalen" Texten ist aber abzuraten, weil die meisten Leser/Zuhörer da zunächst von einem Fehler ausgehen werden.

Answer (score 0):

Wikipedia hat hierzu eine gute Erklärung, allerdings über das Suffix [-ismus](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/-ismus). Dort sind auch viele "Ismen" aufgelistet, vielleicht hilft das ja. Generell bezeichnet das entstandene ein [Abstraktum](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstraktion).

Ich kopiere kurz die aufgelisteten Bedeutungen:

1. Ismen als neutrale Begriffe
2. Ismen als Geisteshaltung und Lebenseinstellung
3. Ismen mit herabsetzender Bedeutung
4. Ismen als Dogmata
5. Ismen als Gegensätze

Mir persönlich ist noch in Erinnerung, dass eine Lehrerin mir mal gesagt habe "-ismus" stehe für eine negative Übertreibung, was wohl aber hier nur für Punkte 3 und 4 so gilt, z.B. "Extremismus".

Es kommt also auf das spezielle Wort an, um erklären zu können was "-ismus" bzw. "-istisch" genau verändert. "Klassizismus" ist z.B. keine negative Übertreibunge von "Klassik", sondern eine Stilrichtung. Ich glaube auch wie *Mac*, dass du hier einer falschen Fährte folgst, wenn du das mit der Endung "-isch" vergleichst, da die von dir gewählten Worte rein zufällig auf "-isch" enden.

- "klassisch" => "klassizistisch"
- aber: "extrem" => "extremistisch"

Noch ein Beispiel: In der Physik bedeutet "relativistisch" soviel wie "die Relativitätstheorie betreffend", wohingegen es in der Philosophie etwas mit dem "Relativismus" zu tun hat, was eine Denkrichtung ist. Das Wort "relativ" hingegen bedeutet etwas ganz anderes. (Wobei ich gerade sehe, dass es hier auch noch "relativisch" gibt als "das Relativpronomen betreffend, als Relativpronomen verwendet".